# li Element inside of a Div Changing Position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a navigation bar at top of the page. On the right side of it, I have a navigation item list, which are list items. This ul is inside of a div item.
[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>David Chu's China Bistro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>

<body>
  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md"> 
    <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="menu-categories.html">
            <span class="material-icons">
            restaurant_menu
            </span><br class="d-none d-md-block"> Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="material-icons">
              info
            </span><br class="d-none d-md-block"> About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="material-icons">
              emoji_events
            </span><br class="d-none d-md-block"> Awards</a>
        </li>
        <li id="phone" class="d-none d-md-block">
          <a href="tel:410-602-5008">
            <span>410-602-5008</span></a><div>* We Deliver</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem is, this div has a large space at the right side, as seen in picture. This causes the telephone number to go up when screen width expands. I want this list item to aligned right, so nothing would change when screen expanded.

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap 4. I have looked everything about flex but nothing worked out. By the way, I am trying to create a responsive navigation menu which will collapse according to screen size. That's why I am using this classes.

I want this items as in image 1 in every condition.(Telephone number is below others)

```
       body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

/** HEADER **/
#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

#logo-img{
    background: url('../images/restaurant-logo_large.png') no-repeat; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}

a.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  color: #557c3e;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
  line-height: .75;
}

.navbar-brand a:focus, .navbar-brand a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}

p.kosher {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: .7em;
}

p.kosher span{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#nav-list > li {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#nav-list a {
  color: #951C49;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav-list a span {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
#phone {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#phone a { /* Phone number */
  text-align: right;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#phone div { /* We Deliver */
  color: #557c3e;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

button.navbar-toggler{
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
li > a:hover, li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  max-width: 220px;
}

#nav-list li:last-child {
  width:100%;
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some code? And just to be clear: You want, no matter what width, that every item is listed under each other instead of side by side?

Comment: Already provided code. I want list items as in image 1 in every condition.(Telephone number is below others)

Comment: Did you try: `max-width: /* amount in px */;`  ?

Comment: Tried, no good.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show only the minimum code required to reproduce your problem; we don't need the contents of the entire page in order to help with your  navigation menu. Reduce both the HTML and CSS to the bare minimum. For guidance please read the "*[mcve]*" page.

Comment: did you try to simply add row to your ul and then col-4 to your 3 first li and col-12 to the last one ? **3rd time I am editing your post, your div over your UL is not closed**

Comment: using rows inside ul is not optimal solution for Bootstrap navigation elements

Comment: Can you add the css you use for this as well? I can't see what's going on with just the html.

Comment: @ThomasTromp this is Bootstrap... take the code and add the bootstrap to a codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: @MaxiGui I know. But is this just pure bootstrap? I would say there is custom css too right?

Comment: Yes, css code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of, we have to add a `max-width` to the `#navbarNav`:

```
#navbarNav{
  max-width:220px;
}
```

Then, to the #nav-list, we add this code:

```
#nav-list {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Now, you want to align the `#navbarNav` to the right. There are several ways we can do that. First of is with flexbox. If you want to go with this step, you have to add the following code to the parent of the `#navbarNav`. Which is the `#header-nav`:

```
#header-nav{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

**However**, this makes sure that **everything** in your #header-nav, is being aligned to the right. So if you are not adding anything else in the `#header-nav`, you can easily use this code.

Comment: That is pretty much equal to a row on ul and col-12 and last li...

Comment: Pretty much, apart from using a row inside an ul.

Comment: @ThomasTromp Phone number is below but there is a huge gap on the right side. I want this ul to aligned to right.

Comment: Sorry, in my code it said width 300px instead of 220px; What is the width you have given it?

Comment: Added some extra code: justify-content: space-between; to the #nav-list. And margin-right: 0px; to the last child of the li.

Comment: Still same, it is broken after 1400px +

Comment: Odd, I get the result as in your image. Also 1400px +. What does your css looks like now? Can you edit your current css in this post? Also, I might have misread what you want, but you want the entire nav-list to be aligned to the right side of the screen?

Comment: @ThomasTromp Yes. Image 1, without any space on the right side.Updated CSS